# why is my code ignoring the input function?

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

when i run this program, it gives me a segmentation fault after runs the printlist function. I'm not sure why the program is completely skipping over the input function. I set the input variable to a number in the function already so it couldn't be some left over value causing it right?

**class function implementation:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "OrderedList.h"
using namespace std;

OrderedList::OrderedList() {
    head = nullptr;
}

OrderedList::OrderedList(const OrderedList& a) {
    ListNode * newNode;
    ListNode * copyNode; 
    if(!a.head){
        return; 
    }else {
        copyNode = a.head; 
        newNode = new ListNode; 
        this->head = newNode;
        head->value = copyNode->value; 
        copyNode = copyNode->next; 
        newNode->next = nullptr;
    }
}

OrderedList :: ~OrderedList() {
    ListNode * nodePtr;
    ListNode * nextNode;
    nodePtr = head;
    while(nodePtr != nullptr){
        nextNode = nodePtr->next;
        delete nodePtr;
        nodePtr = nextNode; 
    }
}

void OrderedList :: insert() {
    int num = 0;
    while(num){
        cout << "Type a number for insertion (type x to stop): ";
        cin >> num; 
        ListNode * newNode; 
        ListNode * prev;
        ListNode * nodePtr; 
        newNode = new ListNode;
        newNode->value = num; 
        newNode->next = nullptr; 
        if(!head){
            head = newNode;
            newNode->next = nullptr; 
        }else {
            nodePtr = head; 
            prev = nullptr; 
            while(nodePtr != nullptr && nodePtr->value < num){
                prev = nodePtr;
                nodePtr = nodePtr->next; 
            }
            if(prev == nullptr){
                head = newNode;
                newNode->next = nodePtr; 
            }else {
                prev->next = newNode;
                newNode->next = nodePtr; 
            }
        }
    }
}

void OrderedList :: printList() {
    ListNode * nodePtr; 
    nodePtr = head;
    while(nodePtr != nullptr){
        cout << nodePtr->value << "     ";
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next; 
    }
    cout << endl; 
}
```

**driver program:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "OrderedList.h"
using namespace std; 

int main() {
    OrderedList A; 
    cout << "Asking user to type and create listA..." << endl;
    A.insert();
    cout << "listA is: " << setw(20) << endl;
    A.printList(); 
    OrderedList B(A); 
    cout << "listB is copied from listA: ";
    B.printList();

}
```

the output looks like this by the way:

```
Asking user to type and create listA...
listA is: 

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Recommendation: add in OrderedList.h.

Comment: The copy constructor is broken. It only copies one node.

Comment: `insert` does  `while(num)`, but `num` is initially zero, so it's just skipped.

Comment: Print looks good, so the bug you're looking for is probably in `insert`. I'd step through it with the debugger and watch what it does.

Comment: okay, the insert function works now thanks to Martel (the print outputs an unnecessary 0 but i can fix that on my own). i'm having trouble figuring out the copy constructor but i'll keep trying because it's something i need to know

Comment: One thing for the copy constructor is you need to copy all of the nodes in the source list. You'll need a loop.

Comment: The copy will look a lot like the print, it's just that instead of printing you create new nodes.